# Cause: zip END header not found

Tags: java, gradle

I get an error while reimport gradle project. *Cause: zip END header not found*. How can i fix it?
I tried to delete all files under .gradle folders but it doesn't work.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:225)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:155)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:169)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:219)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$600(Install.java:27)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:75)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:69)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:107)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:63)
```

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem and I had to change the Gradle version for this:

[image]

you can find available versions here: https://services.gradle.org/distributions/

Answer (score 1):

That means thats something is wrong with your gradle version. You can simply go to: https://services.gradle.org/distributions/ and choose the actual version. Make sure it is the bin version for example:

> https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.1-bin.zip

Then make sure to change the gradle-wrapper.properties

In my case this worked out.